# How to set outlook addins pinned right away?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I set the SupportsPinning to true for outlook addins by modifying the manifest file as shown below.  This allows the pin icon available. By default, the Pin is not selected.  So is there a way to have the addins PINNED right away?

```
<!-- Task pane button -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
  ......
  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
    <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
  </Action>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Users are responsible for pinning the task pane. The add-in just provides such ability. I'd suggest filing a feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .